# Trouble removing elements from list

Tags: c++, list

I have a list of paired strings, I then remove the top element of each list and compare them.
However, when I remove the top element with list size increases substantially.
I have tried pop_front(), made iterators etc. every way I know how and the same problem happens.

```
std::ifstream myReadFile;
std::list<std::pair<std::string,std::string>> startTape;
std::pair<std::string,std::string> pair;

while (std::getline(myReadFile, pair.first , ','))
{
    std::getline(myReadFile, pair.second);
    startTape.push_back(pair);
}
myReadFile.close();
```

startTape { size=8 }

```
std::pair<std::string,std::string> firstCompare = startTape.front();
startTape.remove(*startTape.begin());
std::pair<std::string,std::string> secondCompare = startTape.front();
startTape.remove(*startTape.begin());
```

startTape { size=1753706592 }

when I look into the startTape list it seems to have looped.

(readFile contents are as follows)
N,C /n 
I,G /n 
A,U /n 
H,A /n 
G,M /n 
C,I /n 
S,H /n 
U,N /n

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to remove things from the front of a list you are looking at... strange things can happen. What are you trying to achieve with your code?

Comment: this is the first stage of a merge sort. I am copying the front to two pair variables and then comparing them to see which is bigger.
Then putting them into a new list.

Comment: Can you show minimal code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Do all elements in the list have the same value as the first? This would clear the list if so, resulting in calling front on an empty list, which is undefined.

Comment: All elements are unique, I'll put enough code to reproduce the issue

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem based on what you report. Have you printed out the contents of the list before taking any action on it? It could be a read problem.

Comment: yes, the contents all read in fine. The firstCompare and secondCompare have the correct values, its just the size. A while loop later on depends on the size.

Comment: Well, I get the right values (if I remove the last newline from the input), and the right sizes, and the right contents. Your error must be elsewhere.

Comment: Like @juanchopanza I am very puzzled by this - so I posted the complete program I wrote to attempt to reproduce your problem. It would be interesting to see what output you get when you try running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a complete program that includes all the things you mentioned above
I did change the way the file was read in slightly - I'm not familiar with the way you call getline() where the first parameter is the stream name, so I created a character buffer to read in the individual elements, then copy them to the pair. I also make sure I don't do something crazy at the end of the file, in case there are not two elements read (it works whether there's a \n at the end of file, or not).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

#define BUF 100
using namespace std;

int main() {
  std::ifstream myReadFile;
  std::list<std::pair<std::string,std::string> > startTape;
  std::pair<std::string,std::string> pair;
  char sbuf[BUF]; // temp storage for file read

  myReadFile.open("listOwords.txt");
  if(!myReadFile) {
    cerr << "Error: file could not be opened" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  cout << "file opened successfully" << endl;

  while(myReadFile.getline(sbuf, BUF, ',')) {
    pair.first = sbuf;
    myReadFile.getline(sbuf, BUF);
    pair.second = sbuf;
    if(myReadFile.good()) {
      // only process if both elements were read successfully
      // this deals with the problem of a "half pair" being read if the file is terminated with \n
      startTape.push_back(pair);
      cout << "read a pair: " << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << endl;
      }
  }  
  myReadFile.close();

  cout << "Size of startTape is now " << startTape.size() << endl;

  std::pair<std::string,std::string> firstCompare = startTape.front();
  startTape.remove(*startTape.begin());
  cout << "Size of startTape is now " << startTape.size() << endl;

  std::pair<std::string,std::string> secondCompare = startTape.front();
  startTape.remove(*startTape.begin());
  cout << "Size of startTape is now " << startTape.size() << endl;

  exit(0);
}
```

The contents of listOwords:

```
>cat listOwords.txt 
N, C
I, G
A, U
H, A
G, M
C, I
S, H
U, N
```

The output I get from this is:

```
file opened successfully
read a pair: N,  C
read a pair: I,  G
read a pair: A,  U
read a pair: H,  A
read a pair: G,  M
read a pair: C,  I
read a pair: S,  H
read a pair: U,  N
Size of startTape is now 8
Size of startTape is now 7
Size of startTape is now 6
```

Let me know if you don't get the same results with this exact code?

Comment: I get exactly the same as you, I'm not sure why the error appears on my other code.
But this is a great way of doing it. Thank you

Comment: Glad it worked for you. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're thinking of list directions wrong. The 'top' of the list is the 'back'(push_back, pop_back) or the 'end'(rbegin).

Try to use back() instead of front(), and pop_front() to remove the first element.

Still, the list size changing like that sound more like a bug somewhere.

Comment: first compare does end up having the values N,C and secondCompare is I,G,
These are correct, but the size of the gets broken and a loop I have later, depends on the size.